# Case Sensitive Compilation in GCC

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, gnu-make, case-sensitive

Is there a way to compile C code in a case sensitive way so that it can differentiate between #include "blah.h" and #include "Blah.h". 
Currently I am using `gcc 4.6.2`,and `gmake 3.81` and compiling on ***Windows7*** and ***cygwin***.

My build fails on ***Linux*** due the case sensitivity but compiles perfectly on ***Windows***. I was looking for removing this difference and forcing a case sensitive compilation on ***windows*** also.

Comment: Isn't that a function of the filesystem? On windows, filenames are case insensitive; on Linux they are I believe case sensitive.

Comment: The only way would be to store your source files on a case insensitive file system under linux, e.g. a fat32 partition. You're better off fixing the code to match the filename case.

Comment: On Linux filenames are case sensitive. You cannot force the compiler to consider include filenames as cas insensitive. "bla.h" and "Bla.h" are two completly different names on a case sensitive file system, just as "foo.h" and "bar.h" are completly different.

Comment: I think you are asking about a non-issue. Just compile the code in Linux and the compiler will tell you if you made a mistake. If you dont have access to Linux, use egrep in cygwin and search for lines with both `#include` and upper case letters. That should find faulty lines, since include files are usually lower case in C.

Comment: That's great!! I will have to probably search for the difference using egrep and fix the issue manually! 
Thanks guys.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Perhaps you can't force any current compiler to do this but there's no reason why the compiler couldn't have a flag to ignore case.  It would be handy if you knew there was no possibility of filenames differing only by case, such as when compiling windows C projects on linux.  Not saying it's the best option, but i've seen worse hacks!

Comment: The GCC command line option `-Wnonportable-include-path` is your friend. While it does not prevent compilation of incorrectly cased files, it will issue a warning when it happens, exposing the issue even when you're not building on a Linux platform.